# Replace cell value in specific location

Tags: excel, vba, loops, replace, copy

I have this workbook with 3 columns filled with data. If cells in **col A** find their match value in **col E**, then values from **col E** will be replaced with values from **col B**.

[image]

The code below is giving me the following results:

[image]

But I want to achieve this:

[image]

The question is, how can I make every cell from **col A** loop through every cell of **col E** and replace value from **col B** at the right location? Thank you in advance

```
Sub CopyCells1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long

Dim rng As Range
Set ws = Workbooks("Control.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E1" & Lastrow)

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To Lastrow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Debug.Print Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to step Col E rows using a separate inner for loop.

Comment: @TedroyG Fyi Might be interested in a late post demonstrating an undocumented feature of `Application.Match()`.

Comment: @T.M. I will have a look on your post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to process this via nested looping since for each of the values in column E, you need to find the corresponding match in column A and then set the value of column B back to column E.

```
For i = 1 To 8
  For n = 1 To 8
    If Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value) = Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Value) Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 2).Value)
    End If
  Next n
Next i
```

Comment: Any Idea if I could use Trim on this? In case the values have some blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

**Array alternative without second loop**

It's possible to get all corresponding row numbers in one go by comparing two arrays via `Application.Match()`. In case of findings the client id of column B is entered in the E-column array and written back to target; non-findings (returning an error) are ignored thus leaving the original value.

```
Sub MatchThem()
With Sheet1       ' << change to needed sheet Code(Name)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'assign column data to variant arrays
    Dim a: a = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    Dim e: e = .Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
    'match all elements in column E against column A
    Dim RowNums
    RowNums = Application.Match(e, a, 0)
    'assign results based on A-correspondencies to e array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(RowNums)
        If IsNumeric(RowNums(i, 1)) Then          ' check for valid row number
            e(i, 1) = .Range("B" & RowNums(i, 1)) ' remember client
        End If
    Next
    'write results to target
    .Range("E1").Resize(UBound(e), 1) = e
End With
End Sub
```